# InstallShield's DATABASEDIR set by Custom Action but not (always) taken into account

Tags: visual-studio, installation, installshield

I have an *InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio* project that installs an extension to Visual Studio 2015. Therefore, my installer needs to install parts to the Visual Studio's Extensions folder.

Since the installation folder of Visual Studio can be different per machine, I use a script to find the installation path, then I assign that path to DATABASEDIR. So I have a CustomActions.vbs with something like:

```
Function SetDatabaseDir()
   Session.Property("DATABASEDIR") = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\"
End Function
```

(Except in reality I do a registry lookup to find the right path, but that works, no issue there.)

This custom action is registered as an "After Initialization" action.

The strange thing now, is that when I run the installer, when it askes for the database dir, it shows the right path that my script has defined, but if I click next/next/next, it does not use that path, hence installs incorrectly.
 However, if I run the installer, and when it asks for the database dir, showing the right path, I press the Change button, and then immediately OK to confirm that path, it does use that path and installs correctly.

What am I possibly doing wrong ??

Comment: I used to place a MessageBox.Show call whenever I wanted to start debugging the install action, when it pops up, attach the debugger to msiexec process

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/a/37774367/89999 (you're setting a property too late) but I'm not sure that the limited edition exposes enough functionality to fix this.

Comment: Wel I'm setting the property in the "After Initialization (before first dialog)" moment, as its complete name sounds. So that's before showing the dialogs.. And it is in the limited edition the earliest moment a custom action can run. And in the dialog it does show the right path. Only, If I don't press the Change button, it does not use that path...